# node-formidable creating unnecessary files of zero bytes in size

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, multifile-uploader, formidable

I'm using https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable for uploading files with express.

Although it works well there is a problem: I have a form with 9 inputs of type="file" and if I select 3 pictures and submit the form, formidable creates 9 files in my upload directory with 6 of them zero bytes in size. How can I stop the 6 files from being created?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I found this anomaly too. You can either drop and ignore files of zero bytes, or in your Html form upon submit check for those `<input type='file'>` with no files and do a jQuery `remove()`.